# Пытаюсь создать тест, в котором требуется дать перевод словам с английского на русский

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
/* English words */
var englishWords = ["Blackmail", "Coat", "Skirt", "Recent", "Whole", "Necessary", "Responsible", "Aunt", "Positive", "Efficient", "Familiar", "Frequent", "Convenient", "Opposite", "Suit", "Pass", "Raise", "Consider", "Rest", "Across", "Order", "Definitely", "Weary", "Data", "Native", "Heritage", "Destination", "Comprise", "Numerous", "Rather"];

/* Russian words */
var russianWords = ["Шантаж", "Пальто", "Юбка", "Недавний", "Целый, весь", "Необходимо", "Ответственный", "Тетя", "Уверенный", "Эффективный", "Знакомые", "Частый", "Удобный", "Противоположный", "Костюм", "Сдавать,передача", "Поднять", "Рассматривать, считать", "Отдыхать", "Через,поперек", "Заказ,состояние", "Определенно", "Усталый", "Данные", "Родной", "Наследие", "Место назначениия", "Включать, охватывать", "Многочисленный", "Скорее"];

/* Cheack Answer */
function checkAnswer() {
 var i = 0;
 do {
  var answer = prompt("Enter the translation of the word: " + englishWords[i], "");
  if (answer === russianWords[i]) {
   document.write("Right: " + englishWords[i] + " - " + russianWords[i]+ "<br />");
  }

  else if (answer === null || answer === undefined) {
   var cancel = confirm("Do you want to continue your test?");
    if (cancel != true) {
     alert("Good Bye!");
     break;
    } else {
     i = i - 1;
    }
  }
  
  else  {
   document.write("Your answer: " + answer + ". It is not right" + ". Right: " + englishWords[i] + " - " + russianWords[i] + "<br />"); 
  }
  i++;
    }
 while (i<englishWords.length);
};
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: url(images/fon.jpg) no-repeat;
 width: 500px;
 height: 600px;
}

/* Buttons */
#mainBlock {
 margin-left: 50px;
}

.button {
 position: absolute;
 float: right;
 width: 120px;
 height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #F6F686;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: none;
}

#startTest {
 margin-top: 150px;
}

#addWords {
 margin-top: 200px;
}

#editWords {
 margin-top: 250px;
}

#resetList {
 margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link href="LEW_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="LEW_JS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 
 <div id="mainBlock"> 
   <input type="button" value="Start test" id="startTest" class="button" onclick="checkAnswer()">
   <input type="button" value="Add words" id="addWords" class="button">
   <input type="button" value="Edit words" id="editWords" class="button">
   <input type="button" value="Reset List" id="resetList" class="button">
 </div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Фон, используемый в коде]
Всем привет. Я только начал изучать HTML, CSS и JavaScript и ничего еще не знаю. Вопрос следующий: как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "Start test", и после прохождения теста, все полученные данные теста(правильно/неправильно введен перевод того или иного слова) были выведены не просто на белом фоне, а, допустим, на любом другом изображении Лондона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блок `#area` с абсолютным позиционированием перекрывает ваши кнопки. Те вместо того чтобы нажать на кнопку вы нажимаете на блок `#area`.

Более того, каждый блок с кнопкой тоже с абсолютным позиционированием перекрывает предыдущие. Только удалив все блоки с кнопками, и никому не нужный `#area` можно нажать на кнопку.

Изучайте верстку.

Comment: Спасибо! Я все переделал и теперь функция запускается по клику на кнопку, но как реализовать вывод слов после функции на тот же html-документ и на каком-нибудь красивом фоне или просто в рамочке?

Comment: Как минимум, не использовать document.write. https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-document-write

Comment: Спасибо, пойду учить.

Comment: Вам совет - попробуйте [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Я подключал пару плагинов с jQuery, было забавно. Но я не знаю, что искать и как. Например, если хочу подключить какой-нибудь красивый слайдер, то я так и наберу в поисковике, но если потребуется решить какую-нибудь проблему, например как у меня, то я даже не знаю как найду что-нибудь.
Кстати говоря, я теперь использую document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML для вывода текста в тот самый мой блок с id = "area". Все получается, но innerHTML записывает последнее значение из моего цикла. Не знаете, как сделать, чтобы в блок записывались все результаты теста из моего цикла?

Comment: `document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML + string`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Еще не понял, как реализовать что вы написали, но буду пытаться.